# What is the best tool for Version Control in OS 400 Environment for RPG and COBOL

Tags: version-control, cobol, rpg

What is the best tool (best feature, best price, best support) for RPG / COBOL Version Control under OS 400 development?

I heard about ARCAD and ALDON. Which one is better? Or is there another better tool?

Answer (score 2):

[MKS Implementer](http://www.mks.com/solutions/systemi) is another solution I've used and it's decent.  I can't speak for ARCAD or ALDON.

Answer (score 1):

Aldon is ok.  Haven't worked with ARCAD.  I prefer [Turnover](http://www.softlanding.com/turnover/index.htm).

Comment: Yes, I found it via google. The problem is no support/reseller here in Indonesia. Not like Aldon and ARCAD. Thx anyway.

Comment: +1 for Turnover.  It's a good package.